# AWS サービスでバッチ処理の終了を待ってから別のバッチを開始する方法

Tags: aws

Cloudwatch Event のタイマールールで起動した Lambda で動いてるバッチ A があって
その Lambda が終わった後に実行したい別の Lambda バッチ処理 B があるんですが
いままでは A の中で B を aws-sdk の Lambda.invoke で非同期で呼び出していました

今度 A のあとに実行したいけど B とは依存関係のない別の C というバッチ処理ができて
A の最後に C も invoke するようなコードをかいてもいいんですが
A を管理してるのが別部署で毎回修正お願いするのが大変なので
トリガーイベントのようなものを作ってもらって
後続のバッチ処理はそのイベントをみて開始するみたいに
前後のバッチ内を変更せずに後続処理を追加できるようにしたいです

AWSにそういうことができるサービスってないんでしょうか

CludWatchEvent にタイマールール以外にも S3 PUT でトリガーするようなイベントとかもあるみたいなので
Aの終了時にS3に空のオブジェクトをおいてもらって
そのイベントをトリガーするとかでもいいんですが
もっと直接的にイベントそのものを発火する方法やそのサンプルコードみたいなのってないでしょうか

Comment: Amazon SQSとかはどうですか？

Answer (score 0):

複数のLambda関数の間に依存関係を定義するのであれば、AWS Step Functionsをお勧めします。[ユースケース](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ja_jp/step-functions/latest/dg/welcome.html#application)を参照ください。